# What motivates people to answer questions on Meta?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, meta, motivation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are you on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/why-are-you-on-meta) (requires 10k MSO rep)

Okay, [we're finding out about what motivates people to answer questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/what-motivates-people-to-answer-questions-in-stack-overflow); but what motivates people to answer questions on Meta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like being able to put my voice out there and hope that it is heard when it comes to trying to determine the future of this website. Maybe my 2 cents are worth something when it comes to the development of this idea.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any new, good questions on StackOverflow to answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

- Help people
- Share knowledge
- Camaraderie
- Improve the "state of Stack Overflow"

Gee that sounds familiar.